# Prevent generation of some methods when using Doctrine with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to prevent generation of some methods (for entity classes) when using Symfony 2 command:

```
php ./app/console doctrine:generate:entities ...
```

I want some parameters to be completely protected from outside world.

I know I can create empty setters and getters for this parameters but I better not — for the sake of code cleanliness.

Comment: I´m afraid it is not possible. You´ll have to generate getters and setters manually or remove those you don´t want after running generate entities.

Comment: I believe by making the getter and setter protected/private you can stop the command from overwriting those.

Comment: Thanks @Sgoettschkes it's not a bad idea, but i want this setters and getters completely gone.

Comment: Then you either have to delete them everytime or write your own command (maybe extend the old one if possible) to do this. Or you do like many of us and just not use the command at all (e.g. using IDE capabilities instead)